# What is the Rails Way to quickly access static data at runtime?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have these classes that represent large data structures. The data structures themselves are stored in `JSON` files in my app root.

The data is queried ***heavily*** by my application. As such, I load the data into hashes in constants so that it can be accessed quickly. I do this to avoid the database hits.

I have an `initializer` file that loads this data into a global variable upon application start.

Of course, my tests are failing because that data doesn't exist until certain among my tests are run. As far as I know, these are my options:

1. Re-run that one initializer only in the test(s) I need it.
2. Seed the database appropriately in my test instance.
3. Get rid of that global variable and just do it another way, like load that data into redis or something.

Is one of these preferred from the standpoint of Rails conventions?

Comment: I don't follow: One one hand you're talking about loading JSON files into global variables, on the other you're talking about seeding databases. What does the database have to do with making the JSON files available?

Comment: The JSON files represent data stored in support databases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would drop the initializer.

Instead, define a class which is responsible for loading your JSON files, make a method which lazily loads the data on first access, and [memoize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) the method.

Supposing you have `config/persmission.json` which is a large JSON file...

```
class Config
  def self.permissions
    @permissions ||= load_permissions
  end

  protected

  # only gets invoked once
  def self.load_permissions
    JSON.parse(File.read('config/permissions.json'))
  end
end


Config.permissions # invoke load_permissions
Config.permissions # return cached `@permissions` version
```

Now, any code can access `Config.permission` at any time, and the heavy-lifting of loading and parsing the JSON only occurs on first access.